# Extending query arguments in graphene/graphene_django

Tags: django-models, graphql, graphene-python

How do I add non-field arguments to a GraphQL query in graphene? Here's an example of a use case. I'd like to be able to do:

```
{
  hsv(h: 40, s: 128, v: 54) {
    r
    g
    b
    name
}
```

with this Django model:

```
from django.db import models
from django.core.validators import MinValueValidator, MaxValueValidator,

class Color(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(
        "name",
        max_length=24,
        null=False, blank=False)
    r = models.IntegerField(
        "red", null=False, blank=False,
        validators=[MinValueValidator(0), MinValueValidator(255)]
    )

    g = models.IntegerField(
        "green", null=False, blank=False,
        validators=[MinValueValidator(0), MinValueValidator(255)]
    )

    b = models.IntegerField(
        "blue", null=False, blank=False,
        validators=[MinValueValidator(0), MinValueValidator(255)]
    )
```

and this GraphQL object type and Query based on it:

```
from graphene import ObjectType, IntegerField, Field, relay
from graphene_django import DjangoObjectType

from .django import Color
from colorsys import hsv_to_rgb

class ColorNode(DjangoObjectType):
    r = IntegerField()
    g = IntegerField()
    b = IntegerField()

    class Meta:
        model = Color

class Query(ObjectType):
    rgb = relay.node.Field(ColorNode)
    hsv = relay.node.Field(ColorNode)
    named = relay.node.Field(ColorNode)

    def resolve_rgb(self, args, context, info):
        if not all(map(lambda x: x in args, ['r', 'g', 'b'])):
            # Arguments missing
            return None
        return Color.objects.get(**args)

    def resolve_hsv(self, args, context, info):
        if not all(map(lambda x: x in args, ['h', 's', 'v'])):
            # Arguments missing
            return None

        r, g, b = hsv_to_rgb(args['h'], args['s'], args['v'])
        return Color.objects.get(r=r, g=g, b=b)

    def resolve_named(self, args, context, info):
        if not 'name' in args:
            # Arguments missing
            return None
        return Color.objects.get(name=args['name'])
```

It fails because the arguments aren't accepted. What am I missing?

Comment: (Replying to a comment about using Connection and ConnectionField that now appears to have been deleted.) Would you mind putting together a quick answer showing how this works? I've looked over the relay docs and am not understanding how to pass the ConnectionField values into a query.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer turns out to be simple. To add arguments to the resolver, declare the arguments in the constructor of the field, like this:

```
rgb = relay.node.Field(ColorNode,
    r=graphene.String(),
    g=graphene.String(),
    b=graphene.String())
hsv = relay.node.Field(ColorNode,
    h=graphene.String(),
    s=graphene.String(),
    v=graphene.String()))
named = relay.node.Field(ColorNode,
    name=graphene.String())
```

The arguments may then be included in the query, as shown above.

Comment: Did they change the way it works? That doesn't seem to work anymore (when I print my schema I still only have `customer(id: ID!): Customer`). Even though I created my field using `graphene.relay.Node.Field(Customer, login=graphene.String())`. I am missing something? (graphene version: 2.1.8).

Comment: [In the code](https://github.com/graphql-python/graphene/blob/3f6f4269462ba0f90c62de1140a9e49e0cda2fa5/graphene/types/field.py#L103) it looks like it should work, not sure why it doesn't.

Comment: not working for me either in relay, only in the native graphene fields. that link you show seems to be just the latter.

Comment: There might be some confusion about the difference between `relay.Node.Field` and `relay.node.Field` here. As far as I can tell, the former is a Relay field which doesn't handle extra arguments, and the latter is a plain old field which does (but doesn't have the relay ID).